# Oveflowing fixed position popup, scrolls body beneath

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fixed

Basicly I have popup, that is width:100%; height:100%; and has vertical scroll.

My body has vertical scroll too.

So when I scroll the content of the popup, its scrolls until it can, then continues to scroll the body bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `height: 100%;` and `overflow: hidden` to `body` while the pop-up is shown